# Internet Explorer - Check if permission denied

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following code in Internet Explorer 8:

```
if (window.opener != null && window.opener.foo != null)  window.opener.foo = bar;
```

Sometimes, `window.opener` is set.  But if users open a popup and then navigate away, the attempt to set a property on it should be avoided.

In Firefox and Chrome, this works, because `window.opener` becomes null once the user exits or refreshes that window.  In IE, however, `window.opener` is not null, and `window.opener.foo` gives "Permission Denied" instead of null.  Because of this, `window.opener.foo != null` evaluates to true.

How do I get around this problem, what value matches "Permission Denied" in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the check I use in IE8:

```
if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
    // do what you will with window.opener
}
```

Edit: if you want to display a friendly error, you can try something like this:

```
try {
    if (window.opener && window.opener.foo != null) {
        window.opener.foo = bar;
    }
} catch (e) {
    if (e.description.toLowerCase().indexOf('permission denied') !== -1) {
        // handle it nicely
    } else {
        // some other problem, let it blow up
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This allows you to specifically handle the "Access Denied" error, while not hiding any other potential errors.

Comment: @AndrewLatham if the user refreshes the page then the window is closed, as it should be. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In IE8, for me, refresh resulted in it still thinking window.opener. closed was false.  I'm trying to access a property of the parent page in a popup while showing an error message if permission is denied (which would be the case if the parent page was refreshed or exited).  In Firefox/Chrome, I can detect this by checking if window.opener is null.

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to find out if permission was denied without doing a try-catch, which could be anything.

Comment: @AndrewLatham see my edit, it's not pretty but it may be the only way.

Comment: Fair enough, I came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the properties of window.opener in IE, then passing it to Object.keys() will return a 0 length string.

Example usage:

```
if (window.opener && Object.keys(window.opener).length) {
  // do what you will with window.opener
}
```